# What can be said about the eigenvectors of a normalised DFT matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If we have the DFT matrix $\Omega_n$, where the columns are normalised, can we say that the eigenvectors of a cyclic matrix appear in the rows of the DFT matrix?